# Merge two CSV files into one using AWK

Tags: awk, csv, merge

I am trying to merge two csv files using AWK. If the 1st column in file 1 matches the 1st column in file 2 I want to change file1's 3rd column to the value of file2's 2nd column. If there is no match, make no changes and move on to next row.

file1.csv

```
alice,soccer,24
bob,baseball,21
jessica,swimming,22
mike,running,20
```

file2.csv

```
alice,5
jessica,9
```

desired output:

```
alice,soccer,5
bob,baseball,21
jessica,swimming,9
mike,running,20
```

My code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

    awk -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=","}
        { if (NR==NFR){ 
         array[$1]=$1; 
        } 
        if ( $1 in array ){
         $3=array[$2]
        }
         print
        }' file2.csv file1.csv
```

Comment: Not `array[$1]=$1` but `array[$1]=$2` -- that will actually capture the data in file2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} $1 in a{$3=a[$1]} 1' OFS=, file2.csv file1.csv
alice,soccer,5
bob,baseball,21
jessica,swimming,9
mike,running,20
```

#### How it works

- `-F,`

  This sets the input field separator to a comma.
- `FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}`

  When reading `file2.csv`, this saves the second field under the key of the first field in array `a`.

  *Notice the use of `next`.  This tells awk to skip the rest of the commands and start over on the next line.*

  For example, after reading your `file2.csv`, the contents of array `a` are: `a['alice']=5` and `a['jessica']=9`.
- `$1 in a{$3=a[$1]}`

  When reading `file1.csv`, if the first field exists as a key in array `a`, then this updates the third field to the value stored in `a`.

  The test `$1 in a` is true if the content of `$1` (which we are reading from `file1.csv`) is one of the **keys** (not one of the values) of array `a`.
- `1`

  This is shorthand for `{print}`.
- `OFS=,`

  This sets the output field separator to a comma.

Comment: Thanks that did the job! :)

There is one thing i can't quite wrap my head around. `FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}` will contain `5,9` or what exactly will the array `a` contain? 

If it contains `5,9` the check `$1 in a{$3=a[$1]}` does not make sense to me. Can you elaborate?

Comment: After reading `file2.csv`, the contents of array `a` are: `a['alice']=5` and `a['jessica']=9`.  The test `$1 in a` is true if the contents of `$1` are one of the __keys__ (not one of the values) of array `a`.

Comment: "if the contents of `$1` *in file1*"

Comment: Thanks, that clarified it!